# Can I split INSERT statement into several ones without repeat inserting rows?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have such an INSERT statement:

```
   mtemp = "station, calendar, type, name, date, time"
   query = "INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES ( '%s', '%s', '%s', %s, '%s', '%s' );" 
   query = query % (mtemp, mstation, mcalendar, mtype, mname, mdate, mtime)
   curs.execute(query, )
   conn.commit()
```

The problem is that I can not get the variables: mcalendar, mdate, mtime in this statement. They are not constant values. I would have to access each of them within a forloop. However, the values of mstation, mtype and mname are fixed. I tried to split the INSERT statement into several ones: one for each of the three variables in a forloop, and one for the three fixed values in a single forloop. The forloop is basically to define when to insert rows. I have a list of rows1 and a list of rows2, rows1 is a full list of records while rows2 lack some of them. I’m checking if the rows2 record exist in rows1. If it does, then execute the INSERT statement, if not, do nothing.

I ran the codes and found two problems:

1. It’s inserting way more rows than it is supposed to. It’s supposed to insert no more than 240 rows for there are only 240 time occurrences in each day for each sensor. (I wonder if it is because I wrote too many forloop so that it keeps inserting rows). Now it’s getting more than 400 new rows.
2. In these new rows being inserted to the table, they only have values in the columns of fixed value. For the three ones that I use the single forloop to insert data, they don’t have value at all.

Hope someone give me some tip here. Thanks in advance! I can put more codes here if needed. I’m not even sure if I’m in the right track.

Comment: Posting your current code would probably be helpful

Comment: Now I have it working for a single date! I inserted all the rows I need for one day, so that i have 240 records per day per sensor. What i'm trying to do is to make it working for every day. But if i use: for date in dates:  ....it's repeating the loop for every same date, not different date. How could I tell it to do: for differentdate in dates:... ???

Comment: Don't use the string formatting operator (`%`) to put parameters in your query.  See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly your scenario, but is this the sort of thing you need?

**Pseudo code**

```
mstation = "foo"
mtype = "bar"
mname = "baz"
mtemp = "station, calendar, type, name, date, time"
queryTemplate = "INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES ( '%s', '%s', '%s', %s, '%s', '%s' );" 
foreach (mcalendar in calendars) 
    foreach (mdate in dates) 
        foreach (mtime in times) 
            query = queryTemplate % (mtemp, mstation, mcalendar, mtype, mname, mdate, mtime)
            curs.execute(query, )
```

Comment: is there such a loop named as foreach or u r just thinking of      'for eachone in all' ...?

Comment: i used to use this multiple for loop before , but it never worked well. that's why i did not try it in these codes. anyway i'll try it

Answer (score 1):

One INSERT statement always corresponds to one new row in a table. (Unless of course there is an error during the insert.) You can INSERT a row, and then UPDATE it later to add/change information but there is no such thing as splitting up an INSERT.

If you have a query which needs to be executed multiple times with changing data, the best option is a [prepared statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html). A prepared statement "compiles" an SQL query but leaves placeholders that can set each time it is executed. This improves performance because the statement doesn't need to be parsed each time. You didn't specify what library you're using to connect to postgres so I don't know what the syntax would be, but it's something to look in to.

If you can't/don't want to use prepared statements, you'll have to just create the query string once for each insert. Don't substitute the values in before the loop, wait until you know them all before creating the query.

Comment: Just a side note: an INSERT statement *can* insert more than one row: `INSERT INTO t (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3)` will create three rows. Using `INSERT ... SELECT` can also create more than one row.

Comment: u r right.
One INSERT statement always corresponds to one new row in a table. This sentence makes complete sense. I made it work by ONLY writing one single insert statement. It is awesome

Answer (score 0):

Following syntax works in SQL Server 2008 but not in SQL Server 2005.

```
CREATE TABLE Temp (id int, name varchar(10));

INSERT INTO Temp (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Anil'), (2, 'Ankur'), (3, 'Arjun');

SELECT * FROM Temp;

id |  name
------------
1  |  Anil
2  |  Ankur   
3  |  Arjun
```